# Issue connection Selenoid GGR (Go Grid Router)

Tags: selenoid

I am trying to run nightwatchjs test using selenoid ggr (Go Grid router) but I am getting the below error:

```
- Connecting to un:pwd@ip_add on port 4444...
POST http://un:pwd@ip_add:4444 /wd/hub/session - EAI_FAIL
```

Error: getaddrinfo EAI_FAIL un:pwd@ip_add
‼ Error connecting to un:pwd@ip_add on port 4444.

Below are the various container that's running on my Linux machine (IP_add)

[image: various container info]

Could you please support in identifying the issue?

Also, I am unable to navigate to ggr-ui

[image: ggr-ui unable to access]

Comment: Need to use http://localhost:8888/ping (or IP address instead of localhost) in your browser. Also make sure respective ports are open in VM firewall.

Comment: Hi @vania-pooh When I execute http://localhost:8888/ping it returns me with Jason response

{"uptime":"6m25.372494585s","version":"1.1.2"}

But when I try to navigate to the GGR-Ui dashboard page via http://localhost:8888 or HTTP://ggr-ui:8888 it still returns me with page not found an error 

This site can’t be reached

please suggest how can I navigate to the GGR-UI dashboard similar to selenoid-ui dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I was now able to run the test using GGR.

Following command were run to start selenoid, ggr, ggr-ui and selenoid UI:

```
./cm selenoid start --vnc --port 4445

docker run -d --name ggr -v /etc/grid-router/:/etc/grid-router:ro --net host aerokube/ggr:latest-release

docker run -d --name ggr-ui -p 8888:8888 -v /etc/grid-router/quota/:/etc/grid-router/quota:ro aerokube/ggr-ui:latest-release

docker run -d --name selenoid-ui --link ggr-ui -p 8080:8080 aerokube/selenoid-ui --selenoid-uri=http://ggr-ui:8888
```

To navigate to ggr dashboard:

http://'ip address':8080/

In nightwatch config use following selenoum config:

```
host: '192.168.5.241',
port: 4444,
'username': "test",
'access_key': "test-password",
start_process: false,
```

This way I was able to run the test

Answer (score 0):

Well, to run tests on GGR for me was enough official documentations

https://aerokube.com/ggr/latest/

I configured 2 machines

**On  machine №1** (where was configure ggr + ggr(ui))

You can see my list of configured containers

[list of containers screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01xeh.png)

**On machine №2**

Was configured Selenoid and Selenoid UI

Also do not forget to configure `quota file`(see official documentation)

**See common screen of configuration:**

[screen of common configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA14R.png)